# SEO-Setting website to search dynamic data

Tags: search, dynamic, seo

I want to set my website . It has many user profile which is kind of dynamic.
e.g. http://test.com?profile=2,http://test.com?profile=3.
Whats steps I need to make so that its show all profiles on search engine dynamically.

1) I have an Google webmaster tool
2) Added a sitemap and robot.txt for the site.

After 1 months or so(Indexing is done , as I can on Webmaster tool account)
If I search the profile(say by name) I don't see the user profile in search.
I have added the url parameters as well e.g. here profile.
Am i Missing anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you get to a profile from the home page by basic links alone?

Search engines like to be able to find your pages on their own.

Do a more specific search first. e.g. add site:test.com to your search so only your site is competing.

Check you have not blocked the pages in the robots.txt file or via the robots meta tag on the page.